# I have a PL/SQL code that I dont exactly know what does it do?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Can anyone explain row by row what does my code do? Its a PL/SQL code.
[The databases chart looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JxPJj.png)
[image]

```
DECLARE
    a NUMBER;
    FUNCTION f_avg( p_man_id EMPLOYEES.MANAGER_ID%TYPE)
    RETURN NUMBER IS v_val NUMBER(8,1);
    b NUMBER;

BEGIN
    SELECT AVG(salary), COUNT(salary) into v_val, b FROM EMPLOYEES WHERE MANAGER_ID = p_man_id;
    IF  b=0
    THEN v_val := -1;
    END IF;
    RETURN v_val;
    END f_avg;

BEGIN
    a := f_avg(101);
    IF a < 0
    THEN DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('No data found');
    ELSE DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(a);
    END IF;
END;
```

Comment: That's a horribly formatted piece of code. Notice how the first `begin` (sorry, `BEGIN`) actually belongs to the `function` above it. I would strongly recommend reformatting it in order to understand the structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function `f_avg` calculates average salary for employees whose manager is `p_man_id`:

- if there are no employes whose manager is `p_man_id`, function returns -1
- otherwise, it returns average salary

Main part of the anonymous PL/SQL block calls the function and passes `101` into `p_man_id` and displays

- "No data found" if there are no employees for that manager (i.e. function returns `-1`)
- average salary, if it exists